# browser ignores css printed by php

Tags: php, css, file-get-contents

I have a stylesheet link that looks like below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/example/get_page.php?location=bla.css" id="main_ss" />
```

get_page.php just gets a URL using file_get_contents():

```
if (isset($_GET['location'])) {  
    echo file_get_contents('/example/styles/' . $_GET['location']);
}
```

I can see that the stylesheet file is being fetched properly (for example the text of the file is showing in firebug when I expend the link tag) but for some reason it is ignored by the browser. If I just fetch the CSS file directly of course everything works.

The code can be seen here: [www.specman-verification.com/example/bla.html](http://www.specman-verification.com/example/bla.html)

Any leads? I'm at loss here.

Comment: In the example you provided, the PHP script actually returns some HTML with nothing but a `<script>` element, not a stylesheet.

Comment: Note that this method poses a severe security risk; anybody can try to read the contents of any file on your server using the `get_page.php` script.

Comment: @jeroen, you're right. But this will be used behind VPN for internal sites anyhow, so security is of lesser concern

Comment: @AlexisKing: you're also right. On localhost it returns the stylesheet. I now see that in the link it actually returns this script, so this puzzles me even more...

Comment: I think you should set the header with PHP. So in your php file, you add this line. Before your if statement. `header("Content-type: text/css");`

Comment: @avidane You're welcome! I've added the solution as answer, so other people can see the solution as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the Content-type header like this (do this before you output anything):

```
header("Content-type: text/css");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just trying to load the script get_page.php. To load the CSS file you need:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/example/bla.css" />
```

(or similar depending on the actual path to your CSS file). In other words the href attribute needs to specify the path to your spreadsheet file, not the HTML page file.

Comment: `get_page.php` is trying to load another file (bla.css) and return that in the HTTP response, not sure what you're saying...

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it the right way. I understand what you're doing here. You need a good mechanism to dynamically load external CSS and have the result display normal html in the browser output.

Follow the instructions on this url: http://www.warpconduit.net/2009/05/12/dynamically-load-css-and-js-files-using-php/

This will at least get you to have a mechanism to load external css file with php dynamically. You're definitely missing steps in your code.